# Detect whether previous (shipped) page was empty?

Tags: luatex, emptypage

I use lualatex. TeXlive2023, Linux.

Question: Is it possible to detect whether the previous (just shipped) page
was empty? I do not seek to add or remove a blank page. I do not seek to
move to recto or verso. All of those situations have well-known solutions.
What I seek is merely the information, because page N has a custom macro
that depends on whether page N-1 was empty. It does not need to know
"why" that page was empty. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage(fontspec} % I compile with lualatex. Remove line if pdflatex.
\pagestyle{empty}
% Begin pseudo-code:
\IfPrevPageEmpty{\typeout{FOO}}{\typeout{BAR}}
% End pseudo-code.
\begin{document}
Hello
\clearpage
\IfPrevPageEmpty% Expect BAR.
\null
\clearpage
\IfPrevPageEmpty% Expect FOO.
World
\end{document}
```

The above MWE does not use header or footer, so a page with nothing in its
main text would be truly empty. It would be better if the detection looked
only in the main textblock, so that a previous page with non-empty
header or footer would be "empty" with an empty textblock.

Why I ask: Pages up to N-1 may be edited by one person, and pages from N
may be edited by a different person. The combined document may be edited by
a third person. I want to throw a flag if N-1 and N do not interact
as expected. Not a simple matter of recto/verso. If the third person happens
to be me, I will notice; not necessarily true for others.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `\null` in a document. If created blank pages using more standard means, you could just set a flag and test for the flag. But I'm not sure you can retrospectively get the information. Anyway, as far as LaTeX is concerned, the page *isn't* empty else the second `\clearpage` would have no effect.

Comment: @cfr I work with a custom document class (not article, used for the MWE). I use `\null` all the time, for display positioning on line grid. Never had a problem. But for empty pages, I will re-think what I do there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `nextpage`'s commands to clear to the next odd/even page rather than inserting empty pages manually, you can use the optional argument to toggle a boolean you can then test.

The following provides `\rallgclearpage*[]`. The non-starred version clears to an odd page; the starred to an even. The optional argument may contain content to include on any skipped pages. `\IfPrevPageEmptyTF{}{}` provides a conditional, as do `\IfPrevPageEmptyT{}` and `\IfPrevPageEmptyF{}`, and all three should work in the usual way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nextpage}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \g_rallg_empty_bool
\NewDocumentCommand \rallgclearpage { s O {} }
{
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_rallg_empty_bool
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
  {
    \cleartoevenpage[\bool_gset_true:N \g_rallg_empty_bool]
    #1
  }{
    \cleartooddpage[\bool_gset_true:N \g_rallg_empty_bool]
    #1
  }
  \AddToHookNext {shipout/after} { \bool_gset_false:N \g_rallg_empty_bool }
}
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Nnn \rallg_if_prevpage_empty: { T, F, TF }
{
  \bool_if:NTF \g_rallg_empty_bool 
  {
    \prg_return_true:
  }{
    \prg_return_false:
  }
}
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfPrevPageEmptyT \rallg_if_prevpage_empty:T
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfPrevPageEmptyF \rallg_if_prevpage_empty:F
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfPrevPageEmptyTF \rallg_if_prevpage_empty:TF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Hello
\rallgclearpage
\IfPrevPageEmptyTF{empty}{non}% Expect empty.
\rallgclearpage*
World
\IfPrevPageEmptyTF{empty}{non}% Expect non.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know if there's something better than `nextpage` now, the way `everpage` etc. have been superseded, but this seems to work.

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking in that direction (minus the expl3 code), but was unsure if there was a built-in method that I didn't know. Your answer does what I need.

Comment: Will also look at the edits.